# How to check a received file bytes by web API and save on the sever?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api, web

I have to write a service using Web API. In that method I should receive 2 items:

1. An **Id**,
2. **File(s)**

This method is going to be called from a mobile app. After googling on the subject, in a sample web page, I converted uploaded file to base 64 (using jQuery) and I received it on the server:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Holds the load event results
    var base64 = "";

    //
    function converToBase64() {
        var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];

        var reader = new FileReader();

        // Event handler
        reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
            base64 = reader.result;
            console.log(base64);

        }, false);

        // Fires the load event
        if (file) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        }
    }

    // AJAX request
    $(function () {
        $('#Button1').click(function () {

            var data = {};

            data.Id = "3";
            data.File = base64;
            console.log(data);
            alert("start");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/api/SaveFile",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json"
            }).done(function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                });
            })
        });


</script>

<div>
    <input type="file" onchange="converToBase64()"><br>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

I have no idea whether my solution is correct. Anyway, after receiving on server side, I converted base 64 string to `byte[]`.

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(FileUploadData data)
{
    string converted = data.File.Substring(data.File.IndexOf(",") + 1, data.File.Length - data.File.IndexOf(",") - 1);
    byte[] fileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(converted);

    // Do checking
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Success");
}

public class FileUploadData
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string File { get; set; }
}
```

I've read lots of solutions to same problem about saving bytes into files. But I should not do this before checking extension and size. As it is dangerous to save banned files on physical space, So how can I do these checking before saving on the disk(as a file)? Because .

Comment: As far as I can tell, you don't have the filename or extension available in your Web API method. What type of checks do you want to do? The type of the file determines what vulnerabilities you could be exposed to. Your question is too open ended and we need more information to answer it properly.

Comment: @Snympi ,I should just let Image files to be saved on the disk. not other file extension.

Comment: So you are uploading image files. You have narrowed the problem down, but you still have to be able to tell which image format is uploaded(by using the file extension, such .jpg, .png, .bmp, etc.) In the past some image file types had specific vulnerabilities, but have been addressed since then. Also what checks do you want to do?

Comment: I am going to accept .jpg, .png, .bmp

Comment: And what checks do you want to do?

Comment: @Snympi How can I get file extension from byte[]?

Comment: You would have to store it and pass it in with FileUploadData as an additional field.